# Javascript + PHP /// read barcode

Tags: javascript, barcode

I want to read a barcode using a library to barcode decoder or read by javascript or PHP? I browse many sources but can't reach find one to read the barcode

Comment: Neither of those technologies _can read_ barcodes, as far as I know. Some sort of device, a laser scanner, for example would be needed to read the barcode into data that could _then_ be used by those technologies. At our office, PHP provides an interface (form) that users scan (from hand-held USB and wireless scanners) barcodes from various device serial numbers, tracking numbers, etc that populate the form fields to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't personally tried it, but https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS looks like what you want. It's completely client side, so you don't need any PHP for it, which is good, because performance will probably be better.